# Hyperledger fabric cryptgen tool not creating the admincerts

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am using the cryptogen tool from the hyper-ledgerfabric firstsample, Its does not create the admin certificate inside the
                 **crypto-config/peerorganisation/org1.example.com/msp/admicerts**.

```
./cryptogen generate --output="crypto-config"
```

my crypto-config file

```
          OrdererOrgs:
            - Name: Orderer
            OrdererOrgs:
            - Name: Orderer
              Domain: example.com
              Specs:
            - Hostname: orderer
              PeerOrgs:
            - Name: Org1
            Domain: org1.example.com
           EnableNodeOUs: true
           Template:
           Count: 1
           Users:
           Count: 1
          - Name: Org2
          Domain: org2.example.com
          EnableNodeOUs: true
           Template:
            Count: 1
            Users:
           Count: 1
         - Name: Org3
           Domain: org3.example.com
           EnableNodeOUs: true
           Template:
          Count: 1
          Users:
          Count: 1
```

Comment: you can copy singcerts into admincerts directory both certificate are same

Comment: Why exactly are/were you looking for anything too be in `admincerts`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a new feature in 1.4.3 which allows you to specify an *OU* for admin rather than explicitly putting certificates in the `admincerts` folder.

In your crypto-config, you set `EnableNodeOUs: true` and this automatically enables OUs for all supported roles.

You'll see something like

```
NodeOUs:
  Enable: true
  ClientOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/ca.sampleorg-cert.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: client
  PeerOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/ca.sampleorg-cert.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: peer
  AdminOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/ca.sampleorg-cert.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: admin
  OrdererOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/ca.sampleorg-cert.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: orderer
```

in the msp/config.yaml file ( in your case in *crypto-config/peerorganisation/org1.example.com/msp/crypto.yaml*).

Note the `AdminOUIdentifier` field.  This means that any cert issued by the CA for your org which contains an `OU=admin` is now considered an admin.  The certificate generated for the admin user under your org MSP is also generated with OU=admin (e.g. `Subject: C=US, ST=California, L=San Francisco, OU=admin, CN=Admin@sampleorg` ).

Comment: Thanks @GariSingh for such a detailed explanation of this new configuration.

Comment: `The certificate generated for the admin user under your org MSP is also generated with OU=admin` .. where is it generated? is it inside `crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/admincerts` ??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also faced this problem.

For a workaround check what is the version of your cryptogen tool. Try with 1.4.0 version of cryptogen, it works well.

Comment: i am using cryptogen version 1.4.3